# How to restart or reload Django when using it with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, django, linux, nginx, gunicorn

I recently started to learn Django I am a noob at it still , I just installed django with gunicorn and nginx on a Ubuntu 20 server, and now I am configuring my server but I can't find how to reload or restart Django , any help?

I added my domain to allowed_host and saved the file and its not reloading the config I needed to restart the server to reload and then I needed to go back into the venv stop nginx start gunicorn and start nginx again to work , I can't be doing this at evry change I make , and at this topic any ideea how can I make gunicorn start with nginx corectly?

Answer (score 0):

You can't restart Django directly, that's the point of an application server like Gunicorn. On your Ubuntu, it's almost certain Gunicorn is started via systemd, meaning that the command you need is in the Linux terminal:

`sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

This command will restart the application server service, which in turn will reload Django and apply any changes you've made to your config.

To make Gunicorn start with Nginx correctly, you need to configure Nginx to proxy requests to Gunicorn, but chances are you're going to do that if you make a production-grade server, anyways.

For that you need a new directive in your nginx config, within your `server` directive:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:<your_port>;
        // optional:
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

This sends requests made to whatever you've set up to `localhost:<your_port>`, with your own number of choice for this, obviously. It's important that your Gunicorn service must serve on the URL you specify at `proxy_pass`.

The `proxy_set_header` statements are optional, but can be used to keep important data about the original request. This may actually even improve your security and may help your considerations about it.

Comment: Tanks for the answer, now i can start it much easyer . without stoping and starting nginx , but the reloading problem is still there . if i try to do it its says `Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found` , and i think thats because i am running it in a python venv even if i am in the venv , any other ideeas

Comment: @Andy I'm not aware of the specific config of your system, so if gunicorn.service is not found then I'm not entirely sure. Python venv has nothing to do with it, most likely - just think about it: you can still use every other linux command from the virtual environment! It affects only Python. - Also, sidenote, if you're not familiar with the stack you work with, start reading documentations and tutorials about them.